# Method doesn't delete from database - JPA

Tags: java, jpa

I'm making a simple test. I put a `Project` entity in the database and then delete it. The code gives no errors , but doesn't delete the entity. The code for the `main` and two methods is below. Any help is welcomed.

**Test**

```
public static void main(String[] args) {  
    EntityManager em = EmFactory.getEntityManager();  // My class gives EntityManagaer instances                            
    EntityTransaction tx = em.getTransaction();                                 
    Project p = new Project();
    p.setProjectKey("Key");
    ProjectDAO dao = FactoryDAO.newProjectDAO();

    dao.addProject(p);
    dao.deleteProject(p);

    em.close();                                                                
}
```

**Add method**

```
public void addProject(Project project) {
    EntityManager em = EmFactory.getEntityManager();
    EntityTransaction tx = em.getTransaction();
    try{
        tx.begin();
        em.persist(project);
        tx.commit();
    }
    catch(PersistenceException e){
        tx.rollback();
        throw e;
    }
}
```

**Delete method**

```
public void deleteProject(Project p) {
    EntityManager em = EmFactory.getEntityManager();
    EntityTransaction tx = em.getTransaction();     
    try{
        tx.begin();
        p = em.merge(p);
        em.remove(p);
        tx.commit();
    }
    catch(PersistenceException e){
        tx.rollback();
        throw e;
    }
    em.close();     
}
```

Comment: Seems that you are in the same transaction from the one started in your main method and the em.close() doesn't seems to commit your transaction.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no need to invoke `merge` before you `delete`.

> In order to delete an object from the database it has to first be
>   retrieved and then in an active transaction, it
>   can be deleted using the remove method.